# How to solve MILP efficiently using MIP python? Any other solvers to quickly solve where I have only integer and binary variables alone?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, integer-programming, solver, gurobi

```
from mip import *

q=[[4,5,0,2],[3,2,1,0],[0,1,4,5],[3,2,0,1],[2,1,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[3,4,2,0],[5,0,3,1],[0,4,3,3],[4,0,4,1]]
s=[11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
r=[6,8,4,7]
a=range(0,10)
b =range(0,20)
c = range(0,4)
d =[12,9,6,6]
o = Model()
x= [[o.add_var('x({},{})'.format(i, j), var_type=BINARY) for j in b] for i in a]
y = [[o.add_var('y({},{})'.format(k, j), var_type=BINARY) for j in b] for k in c]
g = o.add_var(name='max_i', var_type=CONTINUOUS)
h = o.add_var(name='min_i', var_type=CONTINUOUS)

for i in a:
    o += xsum(x[i][j] for j in b) == s[i]
for j in b:
    o += xsum(x[i][j] for i in a) == 1
for k in c:
    o += xsum(y[k][j] for j in b) == d[k]
for j in b:
    for k in c:
        o += r[k] *(xsum(y[k][jj] for jj in b if jj <= j)) >= (xsum(( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a )for jj in b if jj <=j)))
for j in b:
    o += (xsum( xsum(r[k] * y[k][jj] for k in c) for jj in b if jj <= j)) - (xsum(xsum( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a) for k in c) for jj in b if jj<=j)) <= g
for j in b:
    o += (xsum( xsum(r[k] * y[k][jj] for k in c) for jj in b if jj <= j)) - (xsum(xsum( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a) for k in c) for jj in b if jj<=j)) >= h
o.objective = minimize(g-h)
o.optimize()
print("Solution with {} found.".format(o.objective_value))
for x in o.vars:
    print('{} : {}'.format(x.name, x.x))
```

"""I have tried to solve the above MILP using python mip and tried cbc, gurobi solvers, i can able to solve it for small problem , lets say when s=[20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and d = [14,13,0,6], and also when length  of s is less than 5, but for the above inputs, it taking too much time (more than 8 hours and i can't wait).

In the above test case, I have 282 variables and 154 constraints only and I have seen that number of variables and number of constraints alone doesn't contribute to how much time, the solver takes to solve. I have 10k variables and 7k constraints in my main problem to solve for.
I have tried constrained programming by limiting the values of variables by lb and ub, it didnt help. How can I solve it better? Help would be appreciated.
( g and h will be integers in all case, so I tried it by initializing as integer variables and giving close lb and ub, It also didn't help)"""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pushing @Erwin's idea further, I got faster solve times by instead introducing variables ry and qx:

```
for j in b:
    for k in c:
        o += ry[j][k] == r[k] *(xsum(y[k][jj] for jj in b if jj <= j))
for j in b:
    for k in c:
        o += qx[j][k] == xsum(( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a )for jj in b if jj <=j))
for j in b:
    for k in c:
        o += ry[j][k] >= qx[j][k]
for j in b:
    o += (xsum(ry[j][k] for k in c)) - (xsum(qx[j][k] for k in c)) <= g
for j in b:
    o += (xsum(ry[j][k] for k in c)) - (xsum(qx[j][k] for k in c)) >= h
```

The optimal objective value turns out to be $3$, with $(g,h)=(15,12)$.

---

As requested, here is the full SAS code, with variables ry[k,j] and qx[k,j]:

```
proc optmodel;
   set ASET = 0..9;
   set BSET = 0..19;
   set CSET = 0..3;
   num q {ASET, CSET} = [
      4,5,0,2,
      3,2,1,0,
      0,1,4,5,
      3,2,0,1,
      2,1,3,2,
      4,3,2,1,
      3,4,2,0,
      5,0,3,1,
      0,4,3,3,
      4,0,4,1
   ];
   num s {ASET} = [11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
   num r {CSET} = [6,8,4,7];
   num d {CSET} = [12,9,6,6];

   var x {ASET, BSET} binary;
   var y {CSET, BSET} binary;
   var g;
   var h;

   con Con1 {i in ASET}:
      sum {j in BSET} x[i,j] = s[i];
   con Con2 {j in BSET}:
      sum {i in ASET} x[i,j] = 1;
   con Con3 {k in CSET}:
      sum {j in BSET} y[k,j] = d[k];

   var ry {CSET, BSET};
   con ryCon {k in CSET, j in BSET}:
      ry[k,j] = r[k] * sum {jj in BSET: jj <= j} y[k,jj];
   var qx {CSET, BSET};
   con qxCon {k in CSET, j in BSET}:
      qx[k,j] = sum {i in ASET, jj in BSET: jj <= j} q[i,k] * x[i,jj];
   con Con4 {k in CSET, j in BSET}:
      ry[k,j] >= qx[k,j];
   con Con5 {j in BSET}:
      sum {k in CSET} (ry[k,j] - qx[k,j]) <= g;
   con Con6 {j in BSET}:
      sum {k in CSET} (ry[k,j] - qx[k,j]) >= h;
   
   minimize Range = g - h;
   solve;

   print x;
   print y;
   print g h;
quit;
```

And here is the resulting output:

```
x 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  
2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
9  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  

y 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  
1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  
2  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  
3  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  

 g  h 
15 12
```

---

An alternative reformulation for your last three constraints is as follows:

```
   var ry_minus_qx {CSET, BSET} >= 0;
   con Con4 {k in CSET, j in BSET}:
      ry_minus_qx[k,j] = r[k] * y[k,j] - sum {i in ASET} q[i,k] * x[i,j] + (if j-1 in BSET then ry_minus_qx[k,j-1]);
   con Con5 {j in BSET}:
      sum {k in CSET} ry_minus_qx[k,j] <= g;
   con Con6 {j in BSET}:
      sum {k in CSET} ry_minus_qx[k,j] >= h;
```

Comment: Just reduction in nz count? Or are there also other things going on.

Comment: Not sure, but nz count reduction was the motivation.

Comment: Hi, @RobPratt, thanks for the resopnse. I have tried the above code snippet, it didnt work for me and i think ry, qx index are interchanged and in the final two constraints, it is ry instead of r. SO, i modified to following and it also didn't work for me

Comment: ```ry = [[o.add_var('y({},{})'.format(k, j), var_type=CONTINUOUS) for j in b] for k in c]                          
qx = [[o.add_var('y({},{})'.format(k, j), var_type=CONTINUOUS) for j in b] for k in c]     
   for j in b:
    for k in c:
        o += ry[k][j] >= qx[k][j]
for j in b:
    o += (xsum(ry[k][j] for k in c)) - (xsum(qx[k][j] for k in c)) <= g
for j in b:
    o += (xsum(ry[k][j] for k in c)) - (xsum(qx[k][j] for k in c)) >= h
```

Comment: Can you help me with how you solved, how you declared qx, ry and which solver you used, whats the solver time?

Comment: I wonder why you used ry[j][k] and qx[j][k] instead of ry[k][j] and qx[k][j]? as the index should be equal to variable y[k][j], so that all variable have same index and is feasible

Comment: It was an arbitrary choice to match the order of your for loops.  You can do it either way.

Comment: Ok, instead of consuming too much time of yours, can you share the entire code of sas/python as the way you solved it, let me figure it out what went wrong with me, implementing your correction

Comment: Thank you for SAS code, i tried using that, then I found out that you haven't included one main constraint according to the problem in the code.                                     
  ```for j in b:
        for k in c:
         o += r[k] *(xsum(y[k][jj] for jj in b if jj <= j)) >= (xsum(( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a )for jj in b if jj <=j)))``` And so I checked the solution manually, It is not feasible for the problem in my question

Comment: And I think you have added it initially and then missed it, Con4 is missing. Anyway I will try if can do in SAS.

Comment: Sorry for that omission.  Corrected now, and optimal is $3$.

Comment: The solution now is feasible, however for qx variable, you used single summation and even in constraints Con4,5,6 where qx appeared. In my question for qx, it needed double summation, that is, cumulative sum over i, then j. Or Do you included it simultaneously? I modified your SAS code for that and tried to run, its been more than an hour, still it's running. Can I know whats the solver time as got for the above output?

Comment: For qx, I used one SUM operator for both indices, so it is equivalent to a double sum.  I let it run in single-machine mode for 20 minutes, got impatient, and then ran in distributed mode, where it solved in about a minute.  I will update my answer with another reformulation idea that might help.

Comment: I have tried the reformulation of SAS code, and its been an hour, I didnt get the output, I'm using single-machine mode only.

Comment: Can we limit the time or GAP, and then to print the best output within that limit in SAS?

Comment: The following imposes a 10-minute time limit and a 10% gap: solve with milp / maxtime=600 relobjgap=0.1;  You can also interrupt the solver at any time and get the incumbent solution by clicking on the Break button (red exclamation point).

Comment: It does solve the issue and provided the optimal for this case. Thank you Robprat. And so, when I have 20k variables and 10K constraints, I doubt this may give near optimal solution alone. So my final two queries are: 1)how to run SAS code via distributed mode as I'm new to SAS, and 2) Is there a way to run python/gurobipy code in distributed mode so that I can get optimal answer in seconds?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128320/discussion-on-answer-by-robpratt-how-to-solve-milp-efficiently-using-mip-python).

Answer (score 3):

How big is the model? Is the time spent in the solver or in generating the model? Can you should a bit of the solver log file (say the beginning and the end)?

I see one thing I don't like:

```
for j in b:
    o += (xsum( xsum(r[k] * y[k][jj] for k in c) for jj in b if jj <= j)) - (xsum(xsum( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a) for k in c) for jj in b if jj<=j)) <= g
for j in b:
    o += (xsum( xsum(r[k] * y[k][jj] for k in c) for jj in b if jj <= j)) - (xsum(xsum( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a) for k in c) for jj in b if jj<=j)) >= h
```

This essentially duplicates a sizable expression. I would use:

```
for j in b:
    o += z[j] == (xsum( xsum(r[k] * y[k][jj] for k in c) for jj in b if jj <= j)) - (xsum(xsum( xsum (q[i][k]* x[i][jj] for i in a) for k in c) for jj in b if jj<=j)) 
    o += z[j] <= g
    o += z[j] >= h
```

(More equations and variables but fewer nonzero elements).

Comment: Thanks Erwin for responding. I have tried already with sizable expression for constraints. The above code is my model for the test case, the time is being spent on the solver.

Comment: It shows modell has 282 vars, 154 constraints and 13960 nzs,

Comment: That is very small. (With #nz's a bit too big for my taste)